# loop through objects in database from starting object to ending object

Tags: java

I have a table named week with columns `weekid`, `weeknumber` and `weekyear`.
Given a starting week I want to get the next 9 weeks (for a total of 10) or the next weeks up to the current week.

I have this:

```
Week weekFirst = weekDao.getWeekByID(20);           
Week weekLast = weekDao.getWeekByID(30);
List<Week> weekList= new ArrayList<Week>();

for(int i=weekFirst.getWeekid(); i<=weekLast.getWeekid();i++){
     weekList.add(weekDao.getWeekByID(i));
     if(weeksDAO.getWeekByID(i).getWeeknumber() == now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)){
          break;            
}
```

But this won't do cause it gets only the weekId instead of Week Itself(The Object)

I need to get the Object Week itself and put it in the list so it doesn't add the Week by the next weekId but it adds according to the next Week Object.

Comment: Could you share your Week class and your WeekDao please?

Comment: Requiring the ids to always be contiguous is a bad idea. That aside, it looks like the DAO is returning the Week object, which it sounds like what you want. Is this not working?

Comment: You should try to remove some of your pronouns to make your question more readable. "It doesn't work because it doesn't do it" does not lend much information. If you have a List<Week>, you cannot possibly add only weekIDs to the list.

Comment: I need the looping algorithm where it should give me the next week objects instead of the next week id

Comment: It sounds like you want you really want is to query for a specific week, and then order the results by week and year. Then iterate the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you can add a method to your DAO:

```
public List<Week> findAllGreaterThanWeekAndYear(int week, int year) {
    //order by year, week
}
```

Or if you really know the ids, you can add the DAO method:

```
public List<Week> findAllBetween(int idFrom, int idTo) {
    Week from = get(idFrom);
    Week to = get(idTo);
    //select w Week w
    //where w.yearAndWeek between (from.yearAndWeek,to.yearAndWeek)
    //order by w.yearAndWeek
}
```

Then your code above becomes:

```
List<Week> weekList= new ArrayList<Week>();
List<Week> weeks = dao.findAllGreaterThanWeekAndYear(...)
List<Week> weeks = dao.findAllBetween(...)

for(Week week : weeks){
 weekList.add(week);
 //TODO: add static getCurrentWeek and override equals
 if(week.equals(Week.getCurrentWeek())){
      break;            
}
```

Depending on how you use it, you could add a specialized DAO method to do the filtering in the query.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem, you're basically saying your weekDAO object isn't returning you the Week object, but instead the Week object's associated ID from the DB.

Your first bit of code:

```
Week weekFirst - weekDao.getWeekByID(20);
```

suggests that "weekDao" is in fact returning a Week object (otherwise it wouldn't compile).

So if you're getting a Week object back, your weekList.add call should be adding a Week object.

Answer (score 0):

`WeekDao#getWeekByID` should return a `Week` object

Use this signature in your DAO

```
public Week getWeekByID(int);
```